# Jquery is checked doesn't get trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/1uvL7tcm/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($('#plainText').is(':checked')) {
        alert('checked');
    }

});
```

What's wrong with my code? the alert doesn't get trigger.

Comment: you need to have a change event handler

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/1uvL7tcm/1/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/1uvL7tcm/3/

Comment: @ArunPJohny what is the best way to write for other checkbox as well? I wouldn't want to select 3 times and use change event for 3 times.

Comment: since all of them has the same name http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/1uvL7tcm/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case the checked condition is only checked once when the dom ready event is fired... what you need is to check the condition whenever the checked state is changed... for that you need to write a handler for the [change event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change) using [change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/) method from jQuery.

Since you want the same handler to be fired for all checkboxes, you can use a common attribute among all the three checkboxes which is its name as a selector. So

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[name="checkbox"]').change(function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            alert('checked: ' + this.value);
        }
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="plainText" value="status">
<label for="plainText">Status</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="image" value="Images">
<label for="image">Images</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="video" value="Video">
<label for="video">Video</label>
```

Comment: Neat! I didn't know you could do snippets on here. Looks like a new feature. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: what time to use this instead of $(this)?

Comment: @ThianKianPhin if you want to access a dom property directly you can use `this`(because this refers to the dom element) but if you want to access a jQuery method you need to use `$(this)`... in this case it is much easier to access the `checked` and `value` property directly than accessing it via jQuery...

Answer (score 1):

Try http://jsfiddle.net/1uvL7tcm/3/

You need to bind to all checkbox elements change event as such:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").change(function(){
    if ($(this).is(":checked")){
        alert('checked');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you have runs once, when the page loads. If your checkbox is checked by default, you will get the alert. I modified your jsFiddle to have it checked by default and you get the alert: http://jsfiddle.net/1uvL7tcm/2/

If what you're looking for is to have this code triggered anytime a checkbox is changed, you will have to add a change handler:

```
$('input[name="checkbox"]').change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        alert('checked');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This..

$('#plainText').on('click',function(){

```
if ($('#plainText').is(':checked')) {
    alert('checked');
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $("input[type=checkbox]").change(function(){
        if ($("#plainText").is(":checked")){
            alert('checked');
        }
    });
});
```